# How to find exact value of a variable?

Tags: math

```
`int s=0;
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
         for(int k=j+1; k<n; k++)
             s++;`
```

what is the exact value of s as a function of n in closed form?
   For above question I tried below and I can not go forward

[image]

Comment: Try working from the innermost summation toward the outermost. The innermost is 1 + 1 + 1 ... how many times? You can therefore replace the innermost summation by an expression in terms of j and n. Repeat that again for each summation. The expressions will get more complicated as you work toward the outside; apply identities to simplify the summations. You will need to derive or look up identities for summing the index and the square of the index, I believe (i.e. what is sum(i, i, i_0, i_1) and what is sum(i^2, i, i_0, i_1)). Good luck and have fun.

Comment: The innermost sum is equal to `n-(j+1)`.

Comment: For the second sum, group all the summands involving `n` together (there are `n-(i+1)` of them) and apply the Gauss sum twice to the remaining summands.

Answer (score 2):

For each choice of 0 <= i < j < k <= n-1, you count 1. That is equivalent to choosing 3 (distinct, unordered) elements of the set {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1} and calling the first i, the second j, and the third k. The number of such choices is the binomial coefficient n choose 3,

[image].

By the way, for most problems of this type, you can [ask Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B1%2C%20%7Bk%2C%20j%20%2B%201%2C%20n%20-%201%7D%5D%2C%20%7Bj%2C%20i%20%2B%201%2C%20n%20-%201%7D%5D%2C%20%7Bi%2C%200%2C%20n%20-%201%7D%5D).

Comment: Since StackOverflow doesn't have the LaTeX support of many StackExchange sites, I used http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution with your help, I hope this is correct.

[image]

[image]